# Python coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-decorators, coroutine

I have a non-async function and an async-decorator function. Is there any way to decorate the non-async function with an async decorator ?

```
async def dec():
    # decorator body

@dec
def my_func():
    # function body
```

Comment: yes of course.. but the caller of my_func must equally be async and use an await call to get the result.

Comment: @smassey It doesn't really work, see my answer for an elaboration. jsbueno's answer answers the question the OP likely _meant_ to ask.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Decorators literally defined as `async def` don't work. It is perfectly possible to produce async functions from decorators, and [jsbueno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761278/1600898) covers that, but you have to use a regular `def` for the decorator itself. The rest of this answer examines what happens when you do try to use `async def` to define a decorator.

What you describe is syntactically valid, but doesn't make sense when run. Consider that a decorator such as:

```py
@dec
def my_func():
    # ...
```

...is syntactic sugar for:

```py
def my_func():
    # ...
my_func = dec(my_func)
```

Obviously, `dec` must accept a function argument, as all decorators do. But that's not enough: since `dec` is an async function, calling it produces a *coroutine object*. This object can be awaited, but not called. In other words, neither of these will work:

```
foo = my_func()        # TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
foo = await my_func()  # TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

What *would* work is `await my_func` - but that would just execute the decorator. Normally decorators are executed at top-level and are expected to return a function that will be called instead of the decorated function. This decorator can't work like that, and has other problems to boot.

Another issue is that `await my_func` would work only once, because the `await` would exhaust the coroutine object. Normally this isn't an issue because you `await` a freshly created coroutine object, as in `await bla()`. If you tried `x = bla(); await x; await x`, the second `await` would also fail.

In conclusion, in current Python `async def` cannot be used to define a decorator.

Comment: "def" in the decorator, and "async def" in the wrapper inside the decorator - that is the key for the dilemma you present (it will work, but with other problems - detailed in my answer)

Comment: @jsbueno Sure, but the answer refers to the situation described in the question, which has `async def` decorator. I did take it literally (responding to _y_ of that particular _xy_), but it _was_ interesting to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Since in decorators, you define the wrapper function inside its body, it can work this way:

```py
def makeasync(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

So, the decorated function would be seem as an async function,and could be awaited. However, if the original func blocks in execution, be it a CPU block, or I/O block, it will stall the async loop, and spoil any advantages from having async code in the first place.

Much more useful would be a mechanism that will run your original function in a separate thread, or even a separate process (for CPU bound functions) -  and, guess what, Python's asyncio does have such an utility - the `run_in_executor` loop method allows you to spec a function call to a non-async function, and await its result: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

If you want that as a decorator, it is almost trivial:

```py
def makeasync(func):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor (None, func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

(by default, asyncio instantiates a concurrent.future.ThreadPoolExecutor - which is good if your function is I/O bound - you can have a separate executor to go with the decorator if you don't want the default settings)